# React children re-render when className changed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, render

React children re-renders, when className changed of the parent changes.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import items from './ItemsList.js';
import Item from './Item';
import './style.scss';

export default () => {
    const isDisabled = useSelector((state) => state.Items.isDisabled);

    return (
        <div className={`container items-container col ${isDisabled ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
            <div className="row items">
                {items.map((obj) => (
                    // All these items re-renders, when parent container className changed
                    <Item key={obj.id} obj={obj} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

When `isDisabled` changed to `true` and `disabled` style appends to the parent `container`, the children `Item` elements re-rendered.

How to append styles/classNames to the parent without re-rendering children elements?

Comment: Is `isDisabled` a state property?

Comment: what does 'disabled' do? can you show us?

Comment: `isDisabled` is the redux state property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with adding `React.memo` to the children item component.

Comment: You should post what the updated code looks like so anyone visiting this question understands fully what the fix you made was.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Items>
```

can be a pure component.

Or

Just use [**shouldComponentUpdate()**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle hook inside Items.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case if `isDisabled` is not a state property.

Comment: `isDisabled` is the redux state property. Your solution is not working.

Comment: @MosiaThabo how ? if the state changes for the `parent` component , the render() of the parent is run , how does the child component implicitly know that it should not re-render ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that, the re-render happens only and only if `isDisabled` is a state property. So using lifecycle methods isn't ideal if a property in question isn't a state property. The OP has to make that clear, either `isDisabled` is a state property or a normal property.

Comment: @user14080657 did you use `pureComponent` or `shouldComponentUpdate` ?, can you paste what your `<Items>` component looks like ? what version of Reat are you using ?

Comment: @MosiaThabo if by state you mean redux-state or just vanilla react state , make sense.

Comment: Otherwise he basically connected the AppState/Redux state to the Component's state. That's why that is happening.

Answer (score 1):

For what you mentioned to be true, there's really only one thing happening, and that is **`isDisabled` is a state property to that parent component**.

And since you're using Redux and calling the `useSelector((state)=>{})`, This actually binds the AppState to Component state. So conceptually, by using `useSelector()` you are treating `isDisabled` as a state property. And by convention with React, any component whose state changes must re-render. So the `parent` in your case, is actually re-rendering.

Here's an important quote that settles everything from Hooks documentation:

> The selector is approximately equivalent to the [`mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) argument to connect conceptually

Here's some references that will help you understand this topic more:

1. [React Hooks API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks)
2. [Connect, mapTopState](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Comment: So how to solve this problem? I was passing props to parent, using connect, but when props are changed, it re-renders children.